# MySQL Inserting date value from a text file

Tags: mysql

I have the following date format

```
28 Aug 2010 17:40:58 +0000
```

Can anyone suggest how I go about getting this into a date or datetime type when inserting into mysql

I'm importing from the file the following way.

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments)
```

I'm unsure as how to handle the date value so it will be structured correctly for mysql.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can convert the dates on the fly. Is it an option to add a second, empty column to the table after the import and convert them in a separate query?

Comment: Yup, changing the schema isnt an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind with lots of warnings and losing information on timezone (unable to convert timezone), you can convert the above answer to:

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq ...
(uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments, @date_val)
SET datetime_column=str_to_date(@date_val, '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

**OR**

make that column to a `varchar`,
after load data into database,
perform the update `update ... set column=str_to_date(column, '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%s')`
and finally change the column data type to datetime

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,136269,136269#msg-136269). It seems that they got solution (briefly, the idea is to add variable to column list, and then set the column value based on formatted value of this variable :
  `load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq .....

    (uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments, @date_val)

  SET datecolumn = date_format(str_to_date(@date_val, '%d-%M-%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y');`